# Override template homedir on FreeNAS 11.3 joined in Active Directory

Tags: truenas, samba4, home-directory

I've joined a FreeNAS 11.3 in an Active Directory and everything works as expected. But one feature that I'm really missing is some kind of override on mapped home directories for users.

By default the directories are with the following template expansion:
`template homedir = /home/%D/%U`

I want to change it to something like: `/mnt/pool0/home/%U`

There's no way on the web interface to do this, and I don't know if changing it directly on `/usr/local/etc/smb4.conf` is a good idea.

What would be the recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page [(https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html)](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) , you are looking for the right configuration item.

```
template homedir = /mnt/pool0/home/%U
```

will make the job.

Comment: Yes sure, I'm aware. But the question is how to make this modification without breaking FreeNAS, since it is an appliance and settings will be overridden.

Comment: The entry `Auxiliary Parameters` in the web interface from FreeNAS is for settings with no GUI available